# EJS is not allowing primitive digits in the terminating condition in for loops

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am rendering out some data stored in a `users` object in an EJS template. However, I only want to render the first 40 items, like so:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<40; i++) { %>
    <% if (users[i].icon_url) { %>
        <a href="<%= users[i].app_download_link %>">
            <img title="<%= users[i].title %>" class="photo" src=<%= users[i].icon_url %>>
        </a>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Doing so results in an error message stating that `Cannot read property 'icon_url' of undefined`, where `icon_url` is a property on the `users` object.

Changing the above code to:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) { %>
    // Same body as above
<% } %>
```

Works perfectly fine. I've searched quite a bit for this, but have come up empty handed. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error would occur when users.length is < 40. When i becomes equal to users.length, then users[i] evaluates to undefined.

Either filter your data outside your view, or you'll need to check for i < max of 40 and users.length.